# Descargar luego de terminar petición - vue-json-excel

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promesas, descarga, callback

Estoy usando la librería **vue-json-excel** la cual me sirve para poder descargar data de un json a excel.

donde en la vista del vue tengo:

```
<div class="column is-narrow" @click="btDispatch">
    <json-excel
      class   = "button is-primary"
     :data   = "routes"
     :fields = "json_fields_routes"
     :name    = "`descarga-rutas.xls`">
    <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></span><span>Descargar entregas</span>
   </json-excel>
```

En donde **:data   = "routes"** es el json que va a descargar:
y esto es la data en la parte de abajo:

```
data () {
  return {
     json_fields_routes: {
       ruta_id: 'id',
       fecha: 'date',
       estado_codigo: 'route_state',
       estado: 'estado',
       vehículo: 'vehicle',
       conductor_codigo: 'worker.id',
       conductor_nombre: 'worker.name',
       hora_inicio: 'date_start_web',
       hora_fin: 'date_end_web',
       entregas: 'dispatches_count',
       pendientes: 'pendientes',
       entregados: 'entregados',
       parciales: 'parciales',
       no_entregados: 'noEntregados',
     },
     json_meta: [
      [
        {
          key: 'charset',
          value: 'utf-8',
        },
      ],
    ],
  }
}
```

Segun la [documentación](https://github.com/jecovier/vue-json-excel) debo hacer esto para poder descargar el excel y funciona correctamente. El problema que tengo es que esto descarga cuando hay **data existente** pero estoy trabajando con data que me llega del server y anteriormente lo cargaba en el **load()** pero aveces suele a ver mucha data y suele demorar un poco al querer ingresar a la sección de descarga, entonces prefiero utilizar un boton de descarga y ahí que recien cargue la data y descargue.
Hasta el momento tengo :

```
methods: {
  btRoute() {
        this.axios.post('/routesdownload/filter_route/', this.params)
            .then((response) => {
              this.routes = response.data.results;
              for (let i = 0; i < this.routes.length; i++) {
                this.routes[i].pendientes = this.filterByStatus(this.routes[i].dispatches, 1);
                this.routes[i].entregados = this.filterByStatus(this.routes[i].dispatches, 2);
                this.routes[i].parciales = this.filterByStatus(this.routes[i].dispatches, 3);
                this.routes[i].noEntregados = this.filterByStatus(this.routes[i].dispatches, 4);
                this.routes[i].date = moment(this.routes[i].date).format('YYYY/MM/DD');
                if (this.routes[i].date_start_web && this.routes[i].date_end_web != null) {
                  this.routes[i].date_start_web
                  = moment(this.routes[i].date_start_web).format('YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss');
                  this.routes[i].date_end_web
                  = moment(this.routes[i].date_end_web).format('YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss');
                } else {
                  this.routes[i].date_start_web = '-';
                  this.routes[i].date_end_web = '-';
                }
                if (this.routes[i].route_state === 1) {
                  this.routes[i].estado = 'Borrador';
                } else if (this.routes[i].route_state === 2) {
                  this.routes[i].estado = 'Publicado';
                } else if (this.routes[i].route_state === 3) {
                  this.routes[i].estado = 'Iniciado';
                } else {
                  this.routes[i].estado = 'Terminado';
                }
              }
            });
      },
}
```

Pero esto simplemente trae la data y la arma según la necesidad pero como podría luego de terminar la peticióm, llamar a la función que descargue con esta librería? podría hacerlo con un callback o una promesa pero como llamo a esa función de descargar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno al parecer la librería no tiene esa funcionalidad y entonces tuve que al componente ponerle un **ref**

```
<json-excel
      ref="droute"
      class   = "button is-primary"
     :data   = "routes"
     :fields = "json_fields_routes"
     :name    = "`descarga-rutas.xls`">
    <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></span><span>Descargar entregas</span>
   </json-excel>
```

y cuando la promesa termina (ya tiene los datos cargados):

```
this.$refs.droute.$el.click();
```

LLamo al componente y descarga.